# Random checkout with 2 types of user using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am looking for random user type checkout for our ecommerce website with 2 types of users :

1. Guest User
2. Loggedin User [Already registered]

What my question is there will be diff. requests and `POST` parameters if I do checkout as `guest` and diff. parameters if I do checkout as `loggedin user`. So here how to handle it.

Random controller can be used but how can I tell jmeter that if random controller do checkout with `guest` then follow X number of requests in test plan otherwise follow Y number of requests for logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option would be using [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) like:

- If Guest

  - HTTP Request relevant for the Guest User
- If Regiestered

  - HTTP Request relevant for Registered User

You can distinguish whether user is registered or not via i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the previous request
2. Configure it to look for something which identifies logged in user and store the value into a JMeter Variable called `foo`
3. Use the following line in the If Controller condition area for the registered user

   ```
   "${foo}" != "null"
   ```
4. Use the following line in the If Controller condition area for the guest user

   ```
   "${foo}" == "null"
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. So my random controller will be top of everything?

Comment: Personally I don't like your "Random Controller" approach, I would rather go for 2 separate [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to represent registered and guest users, it will be much easier to develop and maintain the test this way. The logic which is common for both registered and guest users can be implemented using [Module Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-module-controller)

Comment: If I user 2 thread groups and module controller , how system will hit randomly checkout without random controller? Module controller will behave like random controller?